# Strange appearance of NavBar background image on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The following code for setting bkg image of Navigation bar works well on iOS6, but gives strange result on iOS7.

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bkg.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This is result on iOS 6.

[image]

As you can see something is wrong for iOS 7.

[image]

UPDATE
resized to 64x64px

[image]

Comment: Try `320 × 64` image in iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Guessing because the nav bar is larger on the Y-axis on iOS7 (since it includes the status bar) and your image is just sized for the iOS 6 nav bar. Create an image that is large enough for both versions.

You can see that on ios7, the images is also behind the status bar, and the scrambled part of the image bottom is exactly the height of the status bar.

Comment: This is not a single image, but 50x50 png which is tiling... I guess nav bar height is 44 so it fits there?

Comment: Ok. Well, the nav bar is 44, but as you can see the status bar is included. So maybe an image of 44+20 pixels would work? Or maybe you can tile vertically as well?

Comment: you can see the result for 64x64px.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be tiling...?

Comment: Yep, just stretching in this case.

Comment: Ok, you didn't do anything to get the tiling on the previous image?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea then :-/